# Revert classfile changes without changing the class?

Tags: table-of-contents

I am trying to add dots between the sections and the pages in my table of contents without using the package `tocloft`, since it moved my title from its original position. Right now it looks like this:

[image: current toc]

I have found that if I comment the following line from my `.cls` file, I get the desired output.

```
\let\@dottedtocline\@plaintocline
```

Here's what the desired ouytput looks like:

[image: toc target]

I would like to leave the `.cls` file untouched, as I understand it is best practice.

So how can I suppress the effect of that line from my `.tex` file, instead of modifying the class?

Here is the `\@plaintocline` command definition:

```
\def\@plaintocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
```

Comment: If you use `\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}` then your titles are spared.

Comment: You can use a `\renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}{}`  with the correct number of arguments, being gobbled. Unless `\edef` is used, the `\@dottedtocline` is used when the outer macro is in action, not already on definition, so the redefined command  comes into effect.

Comment: Thanks Harish Kumar for the tip, that worked! @Christian, what do you mean by using that line in my preamble too? I'd still love to see a solution which did not involved tocloft by allowing me just to supress the effect of that line (and not have to load another package)

Comment: @gpedrosa: This depends on the class you are using. I don't know a class which has `\@plaintocline` so I don't know what you want to achieve!

Comment: Thanks for the input @Christian. I did not realize it was a custom defined command. I have just found its definition and will add to the question. Adding `\renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}{}` to the preamble gave me a "missing \begin{document}" error. Adding the same line after `\begin{document}` gave me an unformatted TOC with numbers (such as 11em 37em) all over

Comment: @gpedrosa: That definition is exactly the usual `\@dottedtocline` being define in the LaTeX core file `latex.ltx`. So your class does actually use the traditional `\@dottedtocline` but you want to switch it off? I can't give some advise on `\renewcommand{\@dottedtocline}` because I don't know what you want to achieve!

Comment: Sorry @Christian I forgot to adress this part of your last comment. I hope it is clear by now with my latest edit

Comment: (For reference, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would avoid this confusion in the future.)

Comment: Add thi9s to your preamble: `\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@plaintocline}{\hbox{}}{\hbox{.}}{}{}
\let\@dottedtocline\@plaintocline  
\makeatother`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer No; the definition of `\@plaintocline` is not the same as the kernel's `\@dottedtocline`; a dot is missing (see my comment above).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Ok, the dot is important

Comment: @gpedrosa: It would have been nice to provide this information right from the start and not one small piece after another one. Now the question is answered with something I could have told you right from the start if the question would have been clear! :-(

Comment: Sorry you found it unclear @ChristianHupfer! I will deffinetly try to make new questions if they arise more clear. I did try to keep it as minimum as possible, and I disagree to Johannes_B edit and change the title. This is not what I asked. In fact I already had added the dots to the toc (even in my rustic way). I just wanted to preserve the cls file and know if I could supress the line I provided from the `cls`file from the `tex`.  And I've learned I cannot simply supress it, I have to redefine the command (in this particular case). Thank you for your effort and help!

Comment: You can rollback the edit to its original state if you want, but that title was a bit unclear to me. How about: *Revert classfile changes without changing the class?*

Comment: @Johannes_B I do agree it was a bit unclear, otherwise you wouldn't have felt the need to change it. The title your proposed is a much more suitable imo (for what I had in mind and tried to express)

Comment: Go ahead, change it ;-) Maybe substitute `revert` with `undo`?

Comment: Thanks for the tips and feedback! Changed it with your suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess just adding:

```
\makeatletter
\def\@dottedtocline#1#2#3#4#5{%
  \ifnum #1>\c@tocdepth \else
    \vskip \z@ \@plus.2\p@
    {\leftskip #2\relax \rightskip \@tocrmarg \parfillskip -\rightskip
     \parindent #2\relax\@afterindenttrue
     \interlinepenalty\@M
     \leavevmode
     \@tempdima #3\relax
     \advance\leftskip \@tempdima \null\nobreak\hskip -\leftskip
     {#4}\nobreak
     \leaders\hbox{$\m@th
        \mkern \@dotsep mu\hbox{.}\mkern \@dotsep
        mu$}\hfill
     \nobreak
     \hb@xt@\@pnumwidth{\hfil\normalfont \normalcolor #5}%
     \par}%
  \fi}
\makeatother
```

to the preamble should work. This should redefine `\@dottedtocline` the way it was before the `\let` you mention, i.e. the lay the LaTeX core `latex.ltx` defines it. If you tell me what class you use, I might find an option that switches off that `\let`. Or maybe you can try reading the documentation for it…

**Addenda**

1. As you said, the manual mentions no option to reverse the change, saying instead:

   > A UFPEThesis não oferece nada em particular para a produção da bibliografia ou dos índices. Esse material deve ser criado da maneira usual discutida, por exemplo, em [1].

   Or:

   > UFPEThesis offers nothing in particular for the production of the bibliography or of the indices. This material must be created in the usual manner discussed, for example, in [1].
2. As you notice, the only difference between the two tocline commands is the `\hbox{.}`, which is `\hbox{}` in the `\@plaintocline` macro. That is precisely what makes the dots. Basically (but I might be oversimplifying or getting things plain wrong), `\leaders` takes its argument and repeats it enough times to fill a line, so if it has nothing it puts nothing (`\@plain`), if it has a dot it puts a dot (`\@dotted`). You can have fun changing the contents of that `\hbox` and seeing strange things like:

   > 1. Capitulo segundo * * * * * * * * * * * * * * * `<pagenumber>`

   or:

   > 1. Capitulo segundo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo foo `<pagenumber>`

   if you like :).

A few more details about the command:

- First it checks if the number given as `#1` is greater than `\c@tocdepth`, so if subsubsections are not supposed to be in the toc and you start one it won't create a line. If it is not greater, then it goes into the `\else` branch;
- There, it finds instructions to add vertical space, precisely a stretchable space in order to have some margin of stretchability to be able to avoid collapsing a page into the top section when the page is broken;
- Then it opens a group;
- Then we have some bookkeeping, more precisely some parameter changes;
- After that bookkeeping, which goes on till `\null` and includes `\leavevmode` to start a line, we have a `\nobreak` forbidding a linebreak (we are at the start of the line after all), then we have a negative horizontal space (I wonder why negative), then `#4` is printed, which should be the chapter title or similar;
- After another `\nobreak`, we have the `\leaders` command, which contains `\m@th`, which is a spacing command I don't really know too much about, then a math space `\mkern`, the `\hbox`, and another `\mkern`; so the contents of the `\hbox` will be repeated surrounded by space; naturally, removing `\mkern` will reduce (or eliminate if you remove both `\mkern`s) the spacing around the dots/whatever is in the `\hbox`;
- The `\hfill` strikes me as out of place, but I probably do not know how `\leaders` works; anyway after this a break is forbidden, and a box of the width of a `\@pnumwidth` (a parameter containing a width suitable for page numbers, I should think) is created and placed there, which contains precisely the page number;
- `\par`, so new line, then close the group, then close the `\else` branch and the whole conditional with the `\fi`, and we are done.

Comment: Interesting! The only difference I spot is the `.` in `\hbox{.}`. The way I see is you can't just comment that line from the `tex` file, you have to redefine the whole command (in my case the desired output was the default, found in the `latex.ltx`). Btw it works and not additional packages have to be loaded, thanks!

Comment: @gpedrosa perhaps your class provides an option to revert to the default. I cannot know for sure without knowing what class it is.

Comment: The class I'm using is not on CTAN it is called [`ufpe thesis`](http://www.cin.ufpe.br/~paguso/ufpethesis/) and I believe the manual is not in english, but I assure I've read the manual and did not find an option to do so

Comment: OK, if you say so, I trust you @gpedrosa :). Out of curiosity, what language is it in?

Comment: It is in portuguese :)

Comment: Uh-huh, probably wouldn't have tried then. Eu não falo Portugues :). Though Italian could have helped there :).

Comment: I took a look and concordo com você: nothing on this fix in this manual. It is surprising how easy it was to understand that Portuguese thanks to Italian :).

Comment: Added a couple details to the answer @gpedrosa.

Comment: [Concerning `\leaders`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38424/42315).

Comment: [Concerning `\m@th`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/153398/42315).

Comment: thank you for the follow up and in-depth explanation. Also the effort to decypher the portuguese manual! This alone deserved another upvote :P I guess the ease to understand some bits due to italian relies on the root of both languages since they both are [romance languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romance_languages)

Comment: Indeed @gpedrosa. But for some reason I expected it would help me less than it did :). You're welcome.